# To get data from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

The question I am asking might have already been asked but I have got stuck.
I want to pass data from `EditText` of one activity to `ListView` in another activity
how can I do that.
I have used intent `putExtra` and I am not able implement the get function
so can anyone tell me how to implement get function on `ListView`.

```
private static class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater Linflate;
    private Object convertView;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context)
    {
        Linflate=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ListViewContent.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final ListContent holder;


        if (v== null) {
            v = Linflate.inflate(R.layout.listviewinflator, null);

            holder = new ListContent();
            holder.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
           holder.text.setCompoundDrawables(v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher), null, null, null);

            v.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ListContent)v.getTag();
        }


        holder.text.setText(ListViewContent.get(position));


              return v;
    }

    static class ListContent {
        TextView text;


}



}
private static final ArrayList<String> ListViewContent = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

on this i want to set get method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a model class and serialize it.Pass object of that class

```
 putSerializable("object", object);
```

get object in second class -

```
Bundle bundel = getIntent().getExtras();             
object = (myClass) bundel.get("object");
```

Comment: it is an object  , i have done this in my activity having edit text public static String stringarea=null; Intent i=new Intent(v.getContext(),Mainmenupage.class);
    i.putExtra("sarea", stringarea);
    v.getContext().startActivity(i);